# How to split table of contents across multiple slides with Latex Beamer?

Tags: latex, beamer

I currently am preparing some slides for a presentation and am using Latex with the Beamer package. Currently the sections and subsections of my presentation cause the presentation overview text in the table of contents slide to extend past the bottom of the page.

Is there a way to split my table of contents up so they are displayed across multiple slides?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Outline}
```

The above code will split any over hang across multiple slides.

Comment: This also worked for my [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20660) about bibliographies.  THANKS!!

Answer (score 15):

You can also try:

```
\begin{frame}[shrink]{Outline}
```

The above will try to shrink content to fit frame margins.

Comment: From Beamer’s [User Guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf): *Never* use a smaller font size to “fit more on a frame”. *Never ever* use the *evil* option `shrink`.

Answer (score 13):

You can divide your presentations in parts with

```
\part{1} .... \part{n}
```

then you can show the toc of every part on an other slide with

```
\tableofcontents[part=1]
```

If you use

```
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
```

only the toc of the part will be displayed...

Comment: Linking the solution in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65656/how-do-one-reset-the-section-numbers-in-beamer here for others that would like to reset section numbering between parts.

Answer (score 2):

If you split the table of contents manually, you have more fine control to select a good break point:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
  \only<1>{\tableofcontents[sections={1-4}]}
  \only<2>{\tableofcontents[sections={5-}]} 
\end{frame} 

\section{title1}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\section{title2}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\section{title3}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\section{title4}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\section{title5}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\section{title6}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\section{title7}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\section{title8}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

    
\end{document}
```